# How can I determine if two strings start with the same sub string in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have two strings, and want to determine if the two string start with the same sub string.

```
str1 = "The cat is black. jkhdkjhdsjhd"

str2 = "The cat is black and white."

str1.starts_with_substring? str2
returns "The cat is black"

str1.starts_with_substring? "The cat"
returns "The cat"

str1.starts_with_substring? "Hello, World!""
returns nil
```

I think I could do this with an iterator, but I was hoping for something more built in.

Comment: All three of your examples ask whether *1* string starts with a given string.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `start_with?` and `all?` for that:

```
str1 = "The cat is black. jkhdkjhdsjhd"
str2 = "The cat is black and white."

p [str1, str2].all? { |str| str.start_with?('The cat is') } # true
p [str1, str2].all? { |str| str.start_with?('The cat is not') } # false
```

And as from Ruby 2.5 Enumerable#any?, all?, none? and one? accept a pattern as argument, you can pass a regular expression to check if each string starts with that substring:

```
str1 = "The cat is black. jkhdkjhdsjhd"
str2 = "The cat is black and white."
str3 = "renuncia Piñera The cat is black and white."

p [str1, str2].all?(/\AThe cat is /) # true
p [str1, str2, str3].all?(/\AThe cat is /) # false
```

---

After seeing the question in comments, this might work:

```
str1 = "The cat is black."
str2 = "The cat is black and white."
str3 = "The cat" 

def all_substring?(sentences)
  length = sentences.min.length
  sentences.map { |sentence| sentence[0...length] }.uniq == [sentences.sample[0...length]]
end

p all_substring?([str1, str2, str3]) # true
```

If you can't know beforehand if there's a substring which what to look for, I think you can use the smallest sentence as the substring.

Comment: That's good, thanks.But... how would you do it if you had a bunch of strings and you don't know which (if any) start with the same sub string, and you don't even know what the sub string is?

Comment: That's a very good question. I think you can add some example input and expected output. The more I can think right now is to take a substring from each string and group them to finally get the number of repetitions.

Comment: Here are some examples:

str1 = "The cat is black."
str2 = "The cat is black and white."
str3 = "The cat"
str4 = "The dog is white."

str1.starts_with_substring? str2
"The cat is black"

str1.starts_with_substring? str3
"The cat"

str2.starts_with_substring? str3
"The cat"

str1.starts_with_substring? str4
""

Comment: I had forgotten about that most useful form of [Enumerable#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F), where the argument is a regular expression. I believe that was new in v2.4.

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's from Ruby 2.5 https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/ @CarySwoveland.

Comment: @Glenn, take a look to the update in the answer, does that cover your case? For any other examples, you can add them to your question just updating it.

Answer (score 1):

```
def well_do_they?(str1, str2, str)
  len = str.size
  str == str1[0,len] && str == str2[0,len]
end
```

Comment: Cary, second control should be `str == str2[0, len]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'The cat is black.'
str1 = 'The cat is black and white.'
str2 = 'The cat'
str3 = 'The dog is white'

def matched_substrings(string, *substrings)
  string = string.gsub('.', '')
  substrings.select do |substring|
    substring = substring.gsub('.', '')
    string.start_with?(substring) || substring.start_with?(string)
  end
end

matched_substrings(string, str1, str2, str3)
#=> ["The cat is black and white.", "The cat"]
```

Comment: I like the approach but it would make more sense to use splat arguments instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Any monkey patch to String Class?

```
module MyStringPatch

  def starts_with_substring(other)
    return nil if self[0] != other[0]
    n = (0..self.size).each { |n| break n if self[0..n] != other[0..n] }
    self[0..n-1]
  end

end

String.include MyStringPatch
```

So you can call

```
str1 = "The cat is black. jkhdkjhdsjhd"
str2 = "The cat is black and white."
str1.starts_with_substring str2 #=> "The cat is black"
str1.starts_with_substring "The cat" #=> "The cat"
str1.starts_with_substring "Hello, World!" #=> nil
```